# Exceptionless setter for the second level property

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

When using a composition approach, one class A references class B and class B has some property, is there a way to automatically initialize class B every time one of its properties is initialized? Consider everything is public.

```
class A { 
  B MemberB { get; set; } = null; // Has to stay NULL by default 
}

class B { 
  int Id { get; set; }
  string Name { get; set; }
}

var instanceA = new A();

instanceA.MemberB.Name = "Demo"; // How to auto-instantiate MemberB without exception?
```

**Restrictions**

1. MemberB should stay NULL until the actual use of its property, no default value
2. Syntax shouldn't change drastically, so no property wrappers checking for NULL
3. `DynamicObject` can be used only if I don't have to convert instance to `dynamic` for each use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A backing field for `MemberB` (`_memberB`) that self-initializes on get:

```
private B? _memberB;

public B MemberB {
    get => _memberB ?? (_memberB = new B());
    set { _memberB = value; }
}
```

This might go against your restriction 2, but it is what it is.

An optimization may be using `Lazy<T>` but that requires even more ceremony than displayed here, especially given the property's type probably isn't supposed to change and you still want to support the setter.

Comment: Actually, this may be acceptable because syntax INSIDE the class is ok to change if OUTSIDE the class access to `MemberB` remains unchanged. If no better answer by the end of the day, this will be the way to go.

Comment: Do note that this also means you can never check if it's null (because that will initialize it), and can't serialize/store it as null either.